# Check missing values on a column per item oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like the following:

| ITEM | CORRIDOR |
| --- | --- |
| BOOK | corr1 |
| BOOK | corr2 |
| BOOK | corr3 |
| PEN | corr1 |
| PEN | corr3 |
| PENCIL | corr1 |

My query needs to check that every item is in all the corridors (corr1,corr2,corr3). In case there is an item which is not in all the corridors, the result would give me a table which is:

| ITEM | MISSING |
| --- | --- |
| PEN | CORR2 |
| PENCIL | CORR2 AND CORR3 |

If the previous would increase a lot the computational time it could be enough the following solution:

| ITEM | MISSING |
| --- | --- |
| PEN | CORR2 |
| PENCIL | CORR2 |
| PENCIL | CORR3 |

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to generate all combinations using `cross join` and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select i.item, c.corridor as missing
from (select distinct item from t) i cross join
     (select 'CORR1' as corridor from dual union all
      select 'CORR2' from dual union all
      select 'CORR3' from dual
     ) c left join
     t
     on t.item = i.item and t.corridor = c.corridor
where t.item is null;
```

Comment: In case it would have another column, like price, but each item would only have one price (otherwise it would receive another name like 'book2'), how it would need to be changed so the price would still appear on the result?

Comment: @Nachoagudo . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  A new question should be asked as a *new* question.  However, you might be able to put `price` into the `i` subquery to solve that problem.